# How To Fetch Data From The Local Storage To Page in Javascript

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I want to fetch data from the LocalStorage to the document. Please help me out with the concepts.

```
let p = local = () => {
  let key = prompt("Enter the Key Value")
  let value = prompt("Enter the Value")
  localStorage.setItem(key, value)
  let r = localStorage
  console.log(`The Key is ${key} And The Value is ${r.getItem(key)}`)
}
let c = clearr = () => {
  localStorage.clear()
  setTimeout(() => {
    alert("Your Localstorage Has Been Deleted")
  }, 2000);
}
add.addEventListener('click', p)
clear.addEventListener('click', c)
```

Comment: Also, I'm highly recommending to check:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 0):

In order to get data from `LocalStorage` you can use `localStorage.getItem()`